# Why are so many "Off-topic" reasons listed in the "On-topic" page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It seems to me that the [on-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) pages need a good reorganization. There are many "off-topic" items listed *only* on the on-topic page. This makes it difficult to direct people to the proper page to see why their question is off-topic.

To be honest, the list of off-topic items on the on-topic page is almost as long as the list of off-topic items on the off-topic page.

- Why are all these off-topic items listed in the on-topic page?
- Can we get them moved to the off-topic page with a big, "Click here to see what's off-topic" link on the on-topic page, and, maybe, a big "Click here to see what's on-topic" link on the off-topic page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moderators only have edit access to the on-topic page. I believe the [don't ask](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page is standard across all SE sites. If there are changes to the [on-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, feel free to raise those in meta for the community to agree on and we can make those updates. Otherwise for off-topic page changes, that gets above our pay grade and would need to go up to SE staff.

Comment: Bah! That's frustrating. I get that it's out of your hands, but that doesn't make sense to me. Unfortunately, the on-topic listing of off-topic items seems reasonable, just in a hard to locate place.

Comment: Agreed, it would be nice if we could edit both pages.